# Responsive text inside carousel bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have to place the same text on three different pictures that are placed into a bootstrap carousel. My issue is how to get this text responsive inside the carousel. Do you have any tricks?

EDITED

My question has been misunderstood. I mean I would have a block of text and get it to be responsive inside the carousel. For example A text at the center of the carousel in destkop have to remain at the center in the mobile

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries or set the text using the `vh` or `vw` units.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the font-size inside the carousel to be in em. This way, the text will always be responsive since em is a relative unit...

Answer (score 0):

All ellipsis mean insert your own value.

Bootstrap 2:

```
@media(max-width: ...px) {
.carousel-caption h4 {
font-size: ...;
}
.carousel-caption p {
font-size: ...;
}
}
```

Bootstrap 3:

```
@media(max-width: ...px) {
.carousel-caption h3 {
font-size: ...;
}
.carousel-caption p {
font-size: ...;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div containing the text is centered by default in Bootstrap, and the text itself is in Bootstrap 3.  Either you are using Bootstrap 2 or you have a conflicting style rule.  Either way, add a `text-align: center` to center text.  If the problem is that you have conflicting CSS for the wrapper div, here is how it was centered by Bootstrap to begin with:

```
.carousel-caption {
right: 20%;
left: 20%;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What think you need to do is use a media query to adjust the content from larger display units -ie: sm, md and lg- and make it fit on an extra small device screen.

Below you will find the _index.ejs containing the html. 
Then come the pre-complied CSS rules. The first one is for display units greater than or equal to 768px. These have a large padding to keep the content centered. The next rule is exclusively for extra small devices. Note that the padding has drastically been reduced on the left and right sides to accommodate the content. The font size was reduced as well to make for a more appealing look on mobile phones.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Reviews</h2>
            <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-reviews" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-reviews" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-reviews" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-reviews" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <p>Beefmania is the best pizza I've ever had! It's what I always have when I go there. Highly recommend trying it with the green salad.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <p>The Supreme pizza is to die for!! There's so much of it, too. Make sure you have a light breakfast before you order this one for lunch.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <p>Their outstanding wine selection is a perfect match for any of the pizzas. This includes the house wine which is just as good as the finest, and at a very affordable price.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-reviews" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev fa-stack fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">
                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-stack-1x"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <!-- end of left control -->
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-reviews" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next fa-stack fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">
                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-stack-1x"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

_carousel.less:

```css
.carousel .item {
 padding: @padding (@padding * 12) (@padding * 4) (@padding * 12);
 font-size: (@font-size * 1.5);
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
 .carousel .item { 
  font-size: @base-font-size;
  padding:   @padding (@padding * 3) (@padding * 4) (@padding * 3);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use something like this

```css
.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em; /* small size since this is the default in Bootstrap */
}

.carousel-caption p {
    font-size: 1em; /* small size since this is the default in Bootstrap */
    text-align:left;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) { // Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.3em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.1em;}  
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.4em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.2em;}  
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.5em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.3em;}  
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.6em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.4em;}  
}
```